# How to search for 0,a1[4],* where * is a wildcard in a list of 0,a2,4 0,a1[4],3 0,a1[4],5 .... in tcl

Tags: tcl, wildcard

I tried `lsearch -all $list_ 0,a1[4],*`

a1[4] is stored in a variable
SO basically need
`set var "a1[4]"`
`lsearch -all $list_ 0,$var,*`

Comment: What is `$list_`? Need a [mcve] that includes its definition. (Not just in the question title)

Comment: But remember brackets have a special meaning in wildcard patterns; see http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm#M35

Answer (score 2):

By default `lsearch` uses glob patterns (as described by the [documentation for `string match`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.7/TclCmd/string.html#M37) — it's the exact same matching engine being used). That's good because it means that `*` is a wildcard, but awkward because it means that `[` is *also* special (it starts a character set match). You need some simple escaping, and to keep *that* sane you should put your whole pattern in `{`braces`}` so we don't need to fight with Tcl over what the meanings of bracket and backslash are:

```
lsearch -all $list_ {0,a1\[4\],*}
```

You don't *need* braces; you could write this instead:

```
lsearch -all $list_ 0,a1\\\[4\\\],*
```

But that's *ugly!* And difficult to maintain (trust me on that). So use braces, OK?

---

In the case where you're pulling the subpattern from a variable, things get more complicated. The fix is to use `string map` (or `regsub`) to condition the pattern piece.

```
# Split into three lines for clarity; qvar = “quoted var”
set ADD_BACKSLASHES {[ {\[} ] {\]}}
set qvar [string map $ADD_BACKSLASHES $var]
lsearch -all $list_ 0,$qvar,*
```

Comment: The `regsub` version is `set qvar [regsub -all {[][]} $var {\\&}]`. I don't think that's much clearer.